# wordpress package a script called by http in a plugin way

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpress php script which performs in house administrative tasks.
This script is called using HTTP request.

For instance : http://mywpinstance.com/myscript.php

I would like to package this script in a plugin way.

How can i do this ?
Greetings.
ben

Comment: We need more information! What do you mean by "in house administrative tasks," and "package this script in a plugin way?" Do you want to create a plugin that, when activated, will insert the script reference in `wp_head`?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Hi,in house administrative tasks means synchronizing selected contents between two instance of wordpress. I write a plugin on the distant instance of wordpress to extend the methods, this works fine. Now I want to package my client script as a plugin and called it with a nice url but i dont't know how to. I actually called my client script : www.domain.com/folder/client.php wich runs the XML RPC methods.